# why is it a must to replace the type attribute value when creating list defn and instance via VS?

Tags: list-definition

We have created a VS project and added to it a content type and a list defn that uses this content type.

We have selected the content type and the check box while creating the list definition to auto create new instance.

I have read that the next step is to manually set the type attribute value of the list definition and list instance elements.xml file to 100 or whatever because it is 10000 by default.

What will happen if we do not change this?

Comment: I have personally never changed it from 10000, if I do not provision multiple lists in the same feature

Comment: I read this in book: Share point 2010 development using visual studio.